# There is some gap between parent and child element even margin and padding value is 0

Tags: html, css, node.js, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am developing my website with React framework and I think I face a display problem.

**Tools**

- Visual Studio Code
- Node.js
- Edge Browser
- Chrome Browser

**Libraries**

- Next.js
- TailwindCSS

I write `div` element and 4 child `div` elements with border from TailwindCSS library

**HTML code**

```html
<div className="border m-auto">
  <div className="border">div 1</div>
  <div className="border">div 2</div>
  <div className="border">div 3</div>
  <div className="border">div 4</div>
</div>
```

And I use default `globals.css` from Next.js that set `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;` by default

**Global CSS code**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When I start dev mode `npm run dev` there is some gap display on my element like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GaJp.png).
You will see that there is some gap displaying between parent and child elements. But when I zoom my Edge and Chrome browsers to 200% like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlsPO.png) (and some other values) then the gap disappeared like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU2gR.png). But it display perfectly on my iPad Air and iPhone 5.

**The solution I have tried and has not worked**

- Scale the Windows display setting to 100%.
- Delete TailwindCSS library (no use of a `class` attribute for decorating anymore) and use `style` attribute to decorate elements the same.

```html
<div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>
  <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>div 1</div>
  <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>div 2</div>
  <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>div 3</div>
  <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>div 4</div>
</div>
```

- Create a single HTML file (pure HTML) by Notepad and use `style` attribute to decorate elements the same.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red">
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">div 1</div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">div 2</div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">div 3</div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">div 4</div>
</div>
```

- Use latest version of Internet Explorer, It worked but I know it does not fully support CSS, so I don't count the Internet Explorer in this testing.

**This is a problem of browser displaying or else? Any solution?**

Comment: Have you used the browser dev tools to identify if its padding, margin or line-height?

Comment: It may not particularly fix this problem but I would recommend you to use normalize.css https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ for fix other types of inconsistencies between browsers

Comment: @KyleLambert If you mean "Element" tab, yes. It shown me `margin: -`, `border: 1` and `padding: -` in both parent and all child elements.

Comment: @ozgur I just tried and it has not worked. 

Comment: @Artzeeker I tested your divs here but didn't see any gap at all. https://codepen.io/ozgursar/pen/OJXedGR

Comment: @ozgur Yes, if border width more than 1px. But I got a gap when border width = 1px (even try on Codepen site) this is an [image](https://imageupload.io/Pk46Vu2xRQ.i)

Comment: @Artzeeker I updated the codepen with 1px border width but still no issue with me (on Chrome)

Comment: @ozgur So this is display technical problem (maybe my just monitor). It isn't browser or coding problem. Do you think so?

Comment: I didn't reproduce the issue using the code you provide. It doesn't have gap when browser zoom is 100%: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwNhd.png. You can try your code in other machines to see if the issue persists and check if there're other codes influencing the performance. If the website code is just like what you provide, I think the browser or the code has no issue.